# Как объявить переменную глобальной в Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, переменные

Как объявить переменную глобальной, т.е., например, я создаю переменную в файле MyAppDelegate.m, в проекте на XCode, и хочу чтобы она была доступна в других файлах (классах) приложения тоже. Как это сделать? Может я использую неправильную терминологию в вопросе, но какую знаю, т.к. пока программировал только для веб.

Comment: Допустим, я в файле MyAppDelegate.m создаю изображение NSImage при инициализации приложения. Потом запускаю разные функции, которые находяться в других файлах, и выполняют различные действия над этим изображением. После этого мне нужно опять вернуться в MyAppDelegate.m, чтобы уже измененное изображение использовать. Через параметры функции это изображение не хочется передавать. И еще прикол в том, что не только это изображение будет использоваться, но и другие данные.

Comment: Спасибо, понимаю пока очень приблизительно. Но уже так и чувствовал, что какой-нибудь класс придется городить)) Но на самом деле мне нужна достаточно простая вещь - иметь доступ к некоторым переменным в любом файле приложения.

Comment: > А что вообще плохого в том...

У меня кончились комментарии под своим вопросом.

@baduga, в пределах этого вопроса @aknew дал вам правильный ответ, а Алексей Алыбин и я не советуем вам использовать глобальные переменные и показываем, как это сделать. Если вы не знаете, как, например, объявить класс и хранить в нём данные, смотрите ответ Алексея Алыбина или откройте новый вопрос. Я считаю, что конкретно эта тема уже исчерпана (+ добрый хэшкод не даёт бесконечно комментировать вопросы).

Comment: Создал новый вопрос здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/298823/objective-c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-xcode-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Я присоединюсь к @Stanislaw Pankevich на самом деле, а по поводу моего ответа - как зашел и увидел ответ, ведущий к ошибке сборки то как-то даже не подумал что глобальная переменная не правильный путь сам по себе. Из моей практики - видел такое (глобальную переменную) всего один раз и сразу же переписал этот кусок избавившись от нее :) , иногда использую переменные в пределах одной единицы трансляции (грубо - *.m файла) если в нескольких методах класса (не объекта) надо что-то ограничить.

Comment: @aknew, на самом деле я предполагал что здесь какой-то другой путь для этого нежели глобальные переменные, но не смог сформулировать вопрос правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте синглтон, например

в `Settings.h`

```
@interface Settings : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval autoUpdateLastTimeCall;
+ (Settings *)sharedSettings;

@end
```

в `Settings.m`

```
@implementation Settings

+ (instancetype)sharedSettings {
    static Settings *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Settings alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.autoUpdateLastTimeCall = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Обращение к нужному параметру:

```
[Settings sharedSettings].autoUpdateLastTimeCall = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]
```

Comment: dispatch_once -  потокобезопасный. Следовательно нельзя будет из разных тредов одновременно воспозьоваться переменной. Если я не ошибаюсь?

Comment: Если обратиться к переменной одновременно из нескольких потоков, то ничего плохого не произойдет. Если  одновременно из нескольких потоков попробовать изменить её, то функция (`setter`) ожидает синхронно, пока блок будет выполнен. ссылка на [документацию][1] по GCD


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае не делайте так как советует [@Bimawa](/users/10304/bimawa), объявлять переменные в хедере это верный способ порушить сборку на этапе линковки - хедеры компилятором просто вставляются в m -файлы и вы огребете вместо одной глобальной переменной кучу (в каждом файле где вставлен хедер) глобальных переменных с одинаковыми именами

Правильный способ:

1. добавить к проекту компилируемый файл (.m ) с вашей переменной
2. в .pch добавить объявление что данная перменная присуствует в проекте (при помощи директивы extern)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [[@aknew](/users/2088/aknew)](/users/2088/aknew) правилен, так как отвечает на ваш вопрос в точности, формально, но важно уточнить: для чего вам эта переменная?

Глобальные переменные (не имею в виду констант) - в большинстве случаев - антипаттерн.

Вам нужно определиться со спецификой вашей переменной (domain): чаще всего в такие "глобальные переменные" просятся данные текущей сессии или данные, которые заслуживают отдельного класса контейнера под эту специфику.

Если эта переменная похожа на "данные сессии" - создавайте синглтон-класс вроде Session с соответствующей переменной. Если же это отдельная самостоятельная сущность - создайте класс-контейнер YourDomainFieldClass.

P.S. Алексей Алыбин подсказывает в одном из направлений, которые я показал.

Comment: Допустим, я в файле MyAppDelegate.m создаю изображение NSImage при инициализации приложения. Потом запускаю разные функции, которые находяться в других файлах, и выполняют различные действия над этим изображением. После этого мне нужно опять вернуться в MyAppDelegate.m, чтобы уже измененное изображение использовать. Через параметры функции это изображение не хочется передавать. И еще прикол в том, что не только это изображение будет использоваться, но и другие данные.

Comment: Ну нужно понимать, что вы передаете не данные, ссылки на них. А, следовательно, если вы над ним поделали, какие-то махинации, то достаточно передать управление следующему логическому блоку. И нужно использовать модельный подход. Упаковывайте все в NSObject (POJO в Java) объекты и передавайте ссылки на них между методами.

Comment: @Bimawa, обратите внимание, что @baduga делает: "Потом запускаю разные функции, которые находяться в других файлах, и выполняют различные действия над этим изображением." У него "другие файлы и разные функции", поэтому я предполагаю необходимость некоей централизации его изображения.

Comment: @baduga, обратите внимание на мой ответ. В вашем случае, похоже (говоря навскидку), следует создать отдельный класс-контейнер для работы с вашим изображением YourImageManager, YourImageHolder, YourImageContainer. Понимаете, в какую сторону я рассуждаю?

Comment: > Спасибо, понимаю пока очень приблизительно. Но уже так и чувствовал, что какой-нибудь класс придется городить)) Но на самом деле мне нужна достаточно простая вещь - иметь доступ к некоторым переменным в любом файле приложения.

Возможно, тогда вам стоит подумать в сторону Session или Settings или TemporaryData. Поверьте, это гораздо более чистые логически способы организации данных, чем разбросанные глобальные переменные.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich хм чет где-то подход у @baduga не верный из начально. Хоть ТЗ проси. Глобальные переменные вообще зло, но чтоб NSImage этож грех? Разве нет?

Comment: @Bimawa, пока что я вижу, что @baduga хочет где-то хранить картинку и вижу антипаттерн в том, что он хочет её хранить в глобальной переменной, поэтому пытаюсь поделиться боевым опытом. Также непохоже, что картинка является чем-то вроде "данных сессии", поэтому я и советую завести некий отдельный класс "под специфику" этой картинки и др. переменных о которых говорит @baduga.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, блин чтоб решить данный вопрос, без конференции не выйдет :)

Comment: А что вообще плохого в том, что у приложения есть какие-то данные общие которые где-то храняться? Или ссылки на них, кто его знает, я не силен в теории)) Но уже начинаю понимать, что без теории не получится тут программировать как в php( Про антипаттерн даже спрашивать не буду))

Comment: "@Stanislaw Pankevich, блин чтоб решить данный вопрос, без конференции не выйдет :)" - надо же а я наивно полагал, что мой вопрос из серии простейших, на который есть короткий ответ)

Answer (score -3):

Объявите ее в файлике `ProjectName-Prefix.pch`
Или импортируйте в этом же файлике, хеадер с переменками.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? Что это за файл такой и как там объявить переменную? Просто на тех демо-проектах, которые я изучал, либо нет этого файла, либо он пустой. Интересует не как сделать как-нибудь, а как правильно это делается на Objective C. Упомяну также, что мой проект для Mac, не для ай-фона, если это важно.

Comment: забейте, это ошибочный путь - см. мой ответ ниже

Comment: +1 aknew лучше рассказл )

Comment: pch лежит в директории `Supporting Files`