# Как создать класс для хранения общих данных в Xcode приложении?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

В моем приложении мне хочется хранить где-то некоторые общие данные (как, например, какие-то настройки приложения, только должна быть возможность эти данные изменять в отличие от настроек) и иметь доступ к ним в любых классах (файлах) приложения. Это могут быть любые данные, например, картинки, объекты, или простые переменные. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298776/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-objective-c) рекомендуют объявить класс для этого. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать с примерами кода объявления класса и как к нему обращаться в любом месте приложения.

Comment: Я готов написать развёрнутый ответ здесь, но не имею времени. Надеюсь, кто-то выступит и поможет Вам. Или я напишу позже.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, я готов подождать)

Comment: Не забудьте почитать на досуге про [Анти-Паттерны](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD).

Comment: Посмотрите класс синглтон `NSUserDefaults`. 
p.s. Пока нет @Stanislaw Pankevich. А то вопрос действительно масштабный.

Comment: То что вы хотите называется Singleton, но есть мнения что это антипаттерн.

Почитайте на тему Dependency Injection, или просто забейте и сделайте как попало через Singleton.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, да уже почитал, это типичное неудачное решение если я правильно понял) Теперь нужно узнать про синглтон, что там за поток, который у меня один (и почему он один!), и откуда и куда он у меня течет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синглтон, доступ к которому возможен из любого места в приложении - лучший выход в такой ситуации!

Например класс, реализующий настройки приложения, сохраняющий их в NSUserDefaults при необходимости. Также там можно долгосрочно хранить и иметь быстрый доступ к некоторым пользовательским данным, если в приложении отсутствует база данных или иной метод сохранения на диск.

В данном случае там помимо настроек хранятся еще и userHiScore и maxLevelEarned - для такого скудного набора данных на сохранение такой вариант наиболее приемлемый.

.h файл

```
@interface TRGameSettingsController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger initialLevel;
@property (nonatomic) TRGameControlsType controlsType;
@property (nonatomic) TRGameSoundSetting soundSetting;
@property (nonatomic) TRGameInterfaceTheme interfaceTheme;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger userHiScore;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger maxLevelEarned;

+ (instancetype)sharedController;

- (void)saveSettings;

@end
```

.m файл

```
@implementation TRGameSettingsController

/* при первом оращении создается экземпляр класса, при последующих обращениях возвращается всегда ранее созданный объект singleton */
+ (instancetype)sharedController
{
    static TRGameSettingsController *__sharedController = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedController = [[TRGameSettingsController alloc] init];
        [__sharedController resoreSettings];
    });
    return __sharedController;
}
/* при первом обращении берем сохраненные данные из NSUserDefaults */
- (void)resoreSettings 
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger initialLevel = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerInitialLevelUserDefaultsKey] integerValue];
    self.initialLevel = MAX(1, initialLevel);
    self.controlsType = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerControlsTypeUserDefaultsKey] integerValue];
    if ([userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerSoundSettingUserDefaultsKey]) {
        self.soundSetting = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerSoundSettingUserDefaultsKey] integerValue];
    } else {
        self.soundSetting = TRGameSoundSettingMusic | TRGameSoundSettingSound;
    }
    self.userHiScore = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerUserHiScoreUserDefaultsKey] integerValue];
    self.maxLevelEarned = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerUserMaxLevelUserDefaltsKey] integerValue];
    self.interfaceTheme = [[userDefaults objectForKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerInterfaceThemeUserDefaultsKey] integerValue];
}
/* сохранение в NSUserDefaults */
- (void)saveSettings 
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.initialLevel) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerInitialLevelUserDefaultsKey];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.controlsType) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerControlsTypeUserDefaultsKey];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.soundSetting) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerSoundSettingUserDefaultsKey];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.interfaceTheme) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerInterfaceThemeUserDefaultsKey];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.userHiScore) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerUserHiScoreUserDefaultsKey];
    [userDefaults setObject:@(self.maxLevelEarned) forKey:kTRGameSettingsControllerUserMaxLevelUserDefaltsKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

@end
```

и пример использования в AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[TRGameSettingsController sharedController] saveSettings];
}
```

пример доступа и редактирования данных:

```
  if ([[TRGameSettingsController sharedController] userHiScore] < self.score) {
        [[TRGameSettingsController sharedController] setUserHiScore:self.score];
    }
```

Comment: Нашел еще простой пример синглтона из книги Дэвида Чиснолла "Objective-C. Карманный справочник". 

Можно скачать архив с примерами для книги здесь: http://www.informit.com/store/objective-c-phrasebook-9780321743626 (там файл singleton.m)